# IdentityStoreManager not found in MVC-5 C# Asp.Net Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I working on a MVC-5 application and using Asp.Net Identity for user authentication. I have following nugget packages installed in my project:

- Microsoft ASP.NET Identity EntityFramework version="1.0.0"
- Microsoft.Owin.Security version="2.0.2"
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth version="2.0.2"
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin version="1.0.0"
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb version="2.0.2"
- Microsoft.Owin.Hosting version="2.0.2"

Now my issue is that I want to provide reset password functionality to my users. And for this I need IdentityStoreManager class. But IdentityStoreManager is missing ??

Can anybody please help me find out what I am missing ??

Answer (score 2):

> I want to provide reset password functionality to my users. And for this I need IdentityStoreManager class

The Asp.Net Identity team announces the preview of *Microsoft.AspNet.Identity 2.0.0-alpha1*. Now the password reset functionality is accessible by *UserManager* object. [Check this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx) to find out new functionality available with new alpha version.

Here is the nuget packages for new alpha versions:

- [Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/2.0.1)
- [Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.0.1)
- [Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/3.0.0-beta1)

**Edit:**

Stable versions are announced, links are updated to stable version.